# Bootstrap gruntfile. How to include cssmin task into watch task

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, task, gruntfile

I have a new Bootstrap project. Everything works, livereload, `grunt` command, `watch` command and `cssmin` command, so these tasks are ok.

But, when I run `grunt watch`, there are not minified css files generated (I mean, when any less file change and watch task run automatically). So, I need to add cssmin task to watch task in gruntfile. I don't know how. My gruntfile watch task looks like:

```
watch: {
  options: {
   livereload: true,
  }, 
  src: {
    files: '<%= jshint.core.src %>',
    tasks: ['jshint:src', 'qunit', 'concat']
  },
  test: {
    files: '<%= jshint.test.src %>',
    tasks: ['jshint:test', 'qunit']
  },
  less: {
    files: 'less/**/*.less',
    tasks: 'less'
  }
},
```

How can I add the cssmin task?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced entire less task in my new gruntfile with a less task of a gruntfile of a old bootstrap version. This is the old (it works):

```
less: {
      compileCore: {
        options: {
          strictMath: true,
          sourceMap: true,
          outputSourceFiles: true,
          sourceMapURL: '<%= pkg.name %>.css.map',
          sourceMapFilename: 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>.css.map'
        },
        files: {
          'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>.css': 'less/bootstrap.less'
        }
      },
      compileTheme: {
        options: {
          strictMath: true,
          sourceMap: true,
          outputSourceFiles: true,
          sourceMapURL: '<%= pkg.name %>-theme.css.map',
          sourceMapFilename: 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>-theme.css.map'
        },
        files: {
          'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>-theme.css': 'less/theme.less'
        }
      },
      minify: {
        options: {
          cleancss: true,
          report: 'min'
        },
        files: {
          'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>.min.css': 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>.css',
          'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>-theme.min.css': 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>-theme.css'
        }
      }
    },
```

And this is the new version (don't works):

```
less: {
      compileCore: {
        options: {
          strictMath: true,
          sourceMap: true,
          outputSourceFiles: true,
          sourceMapURL: '<%= pkg.name %>.css.map',
          sourceMapFilename: 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>.css.map'
        },
        src: 'less/bootstrap.less',
        dest: 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>.css'
      },
      compileTheme: {
        options: {
          strictMath: true,
          sourceMap: true,
          outputSourceFiles: true,
          sourceMapURL: '<%= pkg.name %>-theme.css.map',
          sourceMapFilename: 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>-theme.css.map'
        },
        src: 'less/theme.less',
        dest: 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>-theme.css'
      }
    },
```